# How to access the SOAP HEADER in C#

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

How to access the SOAP header into a class.
Scenario: SOAP request is sent form client to web-service.

```
[SoapHeader("transactionInfo", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
public byte[] method1(DocumentInfo templateInfo,System.Xml.XmlDocument xml,string Name)
{"code to get the tags in soap header"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code is working properly, you will find that you have a field named `transactionInfo` defined in your `WebService` class. That field will contain the SOAP Header, in a deserialized form.

I have never done this, but I suspect that if the `transactionInfo` field is of type `XmlElement`, then you will be able to access it as XML. Otherwise, you will be able to access it as a C# object.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Define your custom SoapHeader

```
  public class transactionInfo: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
  {
    public string  Info;
  }
```

2 -  Define you header inside your web service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://..")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public transactionInfo Header  { get; set; }
    ...
```

3 -  Define, inside your web service, a method that uses this SoapHeader

```
  [SoapHeader("transactionInfo", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
```

*[this is the answer to your question]*
**4 -  Access the value of the header from the metod MyMethod using the property**

```
  if (Header.Info == "none")...
```